# How to make Elastic Beanstalk uses Yarn instead of NPM in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yarnpkg

after researching a lot I still cannot make EB use Yarn to install packages.
Below are some ways that I did try:

- Install and run yarn via commands and container_commands in `./ebextensions/options.config` (I got this error: Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_run_yarn failed in cfn-init.log)

  This is my `./ebextensions/options.config`

  ```
      option_settings:
        aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
          NODE_ENV: production

      commands:
        01_install_node:
          command: |
            sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
            sudo yum -y install nodejs
        02_install_yarn:
          test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "Yarn not found, installing..."'
          command: |
            sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
            sudo yum -y install yarn

      container_commands:
        01_run_yarn:
          command: |
            yarn --production
  ```
- Write script to install and run yarn in `./platform/hooks/prebuild/yarn.sh`. I followed [this](https://dev.to/mweibel/deploying-next-js-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-ab4) article and got permission denied error in `eb-engine.log`

Comment: Did you check EB logs what this exception/error message is?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have included errors that I got into my question :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change permission on your local before pushing code:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x .platform/hooks/prebuild/yarn.sh

git commit -am 'message'
```